# TranslateService stream fetching old language

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

```js
export class LobbyPage implements OnInit {
    lottoTxt = ''
  
    //Translate Service
    lotto = ''
    lottery = ''
  
    constructor(
      private constants: AppConstants,
      private translate: TranslateService,
      private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
      
      this.translate.stream('lobby').subscribe(x=>{
        console.log(x)
        this.lotto = x?.lotto
        this.lottery = x?.lottery
      }) 
     }
  
     async ngOnInit() {
      this.setLanguage() 
    }
  
    async ionViewWillEnter(){
      const countryCode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.constants.SEL_COUNTRY))?.countryCode
      this.lottoTxt = countryCode == 'are' ? this.lotto : this.lottery
    }
  
    setLanguage(){
      const lang = localStorage.getItem(this.constants.SEL_LANG)
      this.translate.use(lang)
      this.translate.setDefaultLang(lang);
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="buttons" (click)="goToBase()">{{lottoTxt}}</div>
```

I have an ionic-angular project in which I am using TranslateService. I save the selected language code in login page and fetching it in dashboard page. But when I use translate.stream() and subscribe to a JSON its returning the old language selected and then returns the current language. But the text which I want to show still shows in old language.

Comment: Why you don't use the `translate` pipe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used translate pipe with if/else condition.